# Как просмотреть список всех своих комментариев?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, страница-учётной-записи, комментарии

Список чужих (адресованных тебе) можно увидеть на вкладке Реакции, а своих?

Уточнение: хотелось бы видеть комментарии к удалённым вопросам/ответам.

Comment: Удалил, проверяем.

Comment: Похоже, к удаленным не видно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, к удалённым не видно. Возвращаю метку [meta-tag:предложение].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity

Доступно на личной странице, <kbd>Активность</kbd> -> <kbd>Все действия</kbd> -> <kbd>Комментарии</kbd>

Comment: Вот это я ухитрился не заметить...

Comment: Хм.. А комментарии к удалённым сообщениям там тоже показываются?

Comment: @Qwertiy: снимите временно галочку с ответа, я временно удалю ответ, проверим.

Comment: Готово.​​​​​​​​​