# Можно ли создать ссылку, в которой будет автоматически подставляться id читающего?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, страница-учётной-записи, ссылки

Только что отвечал на [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1748/181472), и в ответе дал ссылку на страницу учетной записи. При этом моя ссылка работает только для меня, поэтому приходится давать ссылку с абстрактным номером. Потом каждый желающий должен будет заменить его вручную на свой.

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/123456/?tab=activity
```

А можно ли дать ссылку так, чтобы она была универсальна для всех пользователей и для каждого вела на его личную страницу?

Например:

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/this/?tab=activity
```

Если такой возможности нет, её было бы здорово добавить. Это позволит писать более удобные руководства для участников сайта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да.

`https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity`

[Проверка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity).

Comment: Работает.​​​​​​​

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну так! B-)