# поиск комментариев в своём профиле

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

близкий по тематике вопрос: [Как просмотреть список всех своих комментариев?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1748/178576)

---

в своём профиле пользователь может просмотреть списки:

- отправленных им комментариев ([«активность» → «все действия» → «комментарии»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments))
- полученных им комментариев ([«активность» → «реакции» → «комментарии»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=comments))

спустя некоторое время общения на сайте эти списки становятся довольно труднообозримыми (у меня, например, на данный момент 160 страниц с отправленными комментариями и 123 страницы с полученными).

возможно ли (и если возможно, то как) пользователю осуществить поиск по этим комментариям, отправленным или полученным им самим?

Comment: Через SEDE всё можно)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, русский текст не ищется (см. ответ). кстати, может быть, ответите на [этот вопрос в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30652664#30652664)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, баг-репорт отменяется. Grundy предложил исправления запросов, они теперь корректно работают с utf8. остаётся открытой вторая часть вопроса, про **полученные** комментарии.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[В английской Мете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286164/6263942) рекомендуют [вот эту штуку](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/273888/) для поиска комментариев по любому из сайтов StackExchange.

Можно выбрать русский сайт или русскую Мету, но, насколько я понял, искать по русским словам эта штуковина не умеет :(

Comment: Grundy [предложил](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30660980#30660980) исправленную версию [запроса](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/505215/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user-now-case-insensitive). вроде, работает и с utf8.

Comment: остаётся найти подходящий запрос для поиска по **полученным** комментариям.